# Can i put Adf.ly ads to my App?

Tags: android, admob, ads

1) my question is if can i put a banner that when we click it, this go to an adf.ly link to earn money? Can i get banned for Google ?

2) If i have an app with ADMOB ADS(**in this app, i only have ADMOB ads**), and i put another App with adf.ly links, can i get banned or no because they are different apps (**in this app i only have Adf.ly links**)?
3) And if i put one app with **Admob Ads** **AND** **Adf.ly links** what happend ?
Sorry for my english, and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a list of other ad SDKs you can use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12934810/800318)

It is fine to use other ad SDK's in your different apps, as far as I am aware. Ones like AirPush (I think that's what it was called) are not allowed anymore as they push ads in the background.

Comment: This question showed up as new... sorry if its too outdated to be useful anymore.